# Django use same object for multiple views

Tags: python, django

In django im making my first app. I'm trying to find a way to share an object between multiple view methods.

e.g. In my views.py I have

```
def lights_on(request):
    hue_connector = HueConnector()
    print(hue_connector.turn_all_lights_on())
    return redirect('/')

def lights_off(request):    
    hue_connector = HueConnector()
    print(hue_connector.turn_all_lights_off())
    return redirect('/')

def light_on(request, light_id):
    hue_connector = HueConnector()
    hue_connector.set_light_on_state(light_id, "true")
    html = "<html><body>" + light_id + "</body></html>"
    return redirect('/')
```

Lets say I want 10 more views in my views.py that need a HueConnector.

How should I create one that can be used by all methods?

Comment: If you need to keep a single state of HueConnector throughout your application, making it (HueConnector) *singleton* might work.

Comment: What do you mean by sharing an object? Do you want to avoid the `hue_connector` instantiation line in every view?

Comment: @EDG956 Yes i want to avoid making a new one in every method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options. I'll describe two here: using a single object instantiated at import time (as proposed by other answers) and class-based views.

### Single instance

Let's say that `HueConnector` can be instantiated at import time and it depends only on some settings (django or external). You could just instantiate it once and use it within your views. I.E:

```py
# app/views.py
hue_connector = HueConnector()

def lights_on(self, request):
    print(hue_connector.turn_all_lights_on())
    return redirect('/')

def lights_off(self, request):
    print(hue_connector.turn_all_lights_off())
    return redirect('/')

def light_on(self, request, light_id):
    hue_connector.set_light_on_state(light_id, "true")
    html = "<html><body>" + light_id + "</body></html>"
    return redirect('/')
```

This is a simple, but not thread-safe (though making it thread-safe is not that complicated).

### Class-based views

You can group http method view handlers in [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/), the only problem is that your views probably share HTTP methods, so you'd have to decide within the handler what to do. I:E: call either `lights_on` or `lights_off` within `post()` based on some condition.

Since you're using separate functions, my guess is that you're using different URLs so, mixing up a bit with [DRF's](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) approach to ViewSet's [http-method-to-action mapping](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) you could create your own `View` class that understand that sort of mapping.

A very bare bones implementation could be something like this (off the top of my head, haven't tested this):

```py
from typing import Mapping, Optional

from django.utils.decorators import classonlymethod
from django.views.generic import View

class ViewWithActions(View):
    @classonlymethod
    def as_view(cls, actions: Optional[Mapping[str, str]] = None, **initkwargs):
        self = cls(**initkwargs)
        self.setup(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if not hasattr(self, "request"):
            raise AttributeError(
                "%s instance has no 'request' attribute. Did you override "
                "setup() and forget to call super()?" % cls.__name__
            )
        if actions:
            for method, action in actions.items():
                handler = getattr(self, action)
                setattr(self, method, handler)

        return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The key takeaway is that subclasses of this class can define as many methods as desired and let the programmer decide, on a per-route basis, which HTTP methods map to which class view method. The `actions` argument to `as_view` controls which function of the class instance is called per http method.

Here's an example on how to use these:

```py
# app/views.py
from hue_connector import HueConnector  # Whatever package you're using

from project.views import ViewWithActions

class LightsView(ViewWithActions):
    def lights_on(self, request):
        print(self.hue_connector.turn_all_lights_on())
        return redirect('/')

    def lights_off(self, request):
        print(self.hue_connector.turn_all_lights_off())
        return redirect('/')

    def light_on(self, request, light_id):
        self.hue_connector.set_light_on_state(light_id, "true")
        html = "<html><body>" + light_id + "</body></html>"
        return redirect('/')

    @property
    def hub_connector(self) -> HueConnector:
        return HueConnector()
```

```py
# app/urls.py
from django.urls import path

from app.views import LightsView
...

urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    path("lights/on", LightsView.as_view({"post": "lights_on"})),
    path("lights/off", LightsView.as_view({"post": "lights_off"})),
    path("lights/<int:light_id>/on", LightsView.as_view({"post": "light_on"})),
    ...,
]

...
```

This would be my preferred option because, by modifying the class to accept the HueConnector class (or a hueconnector factory) as a dependency, it'd make testing easier by passing it fake implementations during tests instead of monkey patching.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do is have `hue_connector = HueConnector()` in another file let's say `utils.py` then import it and use it as you please in all views you want.i.e

```py
# utils.py

hue_connector = HueConnector()
```

```py
# views.py

from .utils import hue_connector
### Proceed using in your views
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a global variable and can access it from other functions.

```
def lights_on(request):
    global hue_connector
    hue_connector = HueConnector()
    print(hue_connector.turn_all_lights_on())
    return redirect('/')
```